# Use a expression & HTML in Visualforce if statement

Tags: visualforce

I have HTML and an expression I want to be displayed if the field as a value. If it doesn't, don't display it at all.

```
{! IF( ISBLANK(GoEvent.Event_Time_End__c), '', '<b>End Time:</b> {!GoEvent.Event_Time_End__c}' ) }
```

I think I have my condition setup properly, but the HTML isn't rendering and the proper value from the expression isn't displaying. Looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your code to work as you intended you need to wrap your output in an apex:outputText and set escape="false".  Note that using escape=false has security implications if you are injecting values the user can edit see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_scontrols.htm

Secondly, the reason you are seeing the # is that you are already inside visualforce syntax with the !IF so no need for the second {!} construct.

Finally I prefer to concatenate the string and visualforce syntax rather than mix.

So a working version would be something like:

```
<apex:outputText value="{! IF( ISBLANK(GoEvent.Event_Time_End__c), '', '<b>End Time:</b>' + GoEvent.Event_Time_End__c ) }" escape="false"/>
```

however, given your code is effectively saying only show the output if not null I'd think you are better off with something like this:

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="false" rendered="{!!ISBLANK(GoEvent.Event_Time_End__c)}">
    <b>End Time:</b><apex:outputField value="{!GoEvent.Event_Time_End__c}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

This is output that is only rendered if the Time isn't blank and output field will localise the time based on user locale etc.